# cant impersonate on hive server2

Tags: hadoop, hive, impersonation

Im trying to connect to hive server 2 through a JDBC connector, but Im getting the error:

```
'user x cant impersonate y'
```

I added these properties to my core-site.xml file:

```
 <property>
   <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hive.hosts</name>
   <value>*</value>
 </property>

 <property>
   <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hive.groups</name>
   <value>*</value>
 </property>
```

Also, in hive-site.xml I have:

```
  <property>
    <name>hive.server2.enable.doAs</name>
    <value>true</value>
    <description>
    Setting this property to true will have HiveServer2 execute
    Hive operations as the user making the calls to it.
    </description>
 </property>
```

I have my authentication set to none and I am connecting as anonymous. I have restarted my cluster since changing the config files as well as running:

```
hadoop fs -chmod g+w /user/hive/warehouse
hadoop fs -chmod g+w /tmp
```

Can anyone suggest why Im still getting the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to connect as user named `anonymous`, the properties should be

```
<property>
     <name>hadoop.proxyuser.anonymous.hosts</name> 
     <value>*</value> 
</property> 
<property>
     <name>hadoop.proxyuser.anonymous.groups</name>
     <value>*</value>
</property>
```